# How to build Android with Xerces

Tags: android, android-ndk, xerces, xerces-c

I want to use Xerces with AndroidNDK.
I want to build a static library for Xerces for Android in Ubuntu, a virtual environment.

Does anyone know of a specific method?

I tried setting the following environment variables, but
"Xerces cannot function without a transcoder"
It will stop at.

```
export NDK=｛AndroidNDK path｝
export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
export ANDROID_VERSION=21
export TARGET=aarch64-linux-android
export AR=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-ar
export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang
export AS=$CC
export CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang++
export LD=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/ld
export RANLIB=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-ranlib
export STRIP=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-strip
./configure --host=$TARGET --prefix=｛Library output path｝
make & make install
```